# Ontology Dataset for "Project"?

Tags: dataset, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I am looking for a ontology dataset, which can describe the concept: "Project". For example:

- the type of the project(new project, improvement, translate...)
- industries involved in the project(mobile application, design, music)
- products of the project

but i can't even find a keyword for such a case.

Are there any suitable datasets for my case?

Comment: Have you look on lov.okfn.org

Comment: An interesting question, but off topic for Stack Overflow: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  You might have better luck on answers.semanticweb.com, where these kinds of questions are more on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one : http://ckan.citek.ipn.pt/dataset/r-d-industry-ontology-and-data

Also, check the below website for similar data sets:

http://datahub.io/dataset